# Tuning local Remote Desktop parameters

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am using Remote Desktop Protocol on Windows 10 in my local LAN. It works quite well but it feels not snappy in two situations:

1. Scrolling
2. Typing

These affect my brain heavily on browsers and text editors.

**Are there ways to optimize the remote connection speed (in the sense of screen refresh rate) with RDP even further?**
My goal is to only use the client machine for RDP connections, so the speed and visual performance should be top notch.

Details:

- Client computer is on Gigabit-LAN and host computer is on the very latest Intel Wireless chip with 5 GHz network
- Client computer is Windows 10 Education and host computer is Windows 10 Pro

---

What I did so far:

**Editing the group policies**

Following [an MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn567648(v=vs.85).aspx) which gives options and applied the following settings via group policy editor on the host even though I am not sure if they affect client installations (both are normal Windows 10 Pro machines). Under *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Remote Session Environment > RemoteRX for Windows Server 2008 R2*:

- *Configure RemoteFX* set to enabled
- *Optimize visual experience for Remote Desktop Service Sessions* set to enabled and "multimedia"
- *Optimize visual experience when using RemoteFX* set to enabled and "highest"

**Modifying .rdp file**

Irrelevant to video but for audio, adding `audioqualitymode:i:2` was nice.

Answer (score 0):

I list below some advice which might help:

- In the "Display" tab reduce the Color Depth down to 15 or 16-bit.
  The lower the color setting the faster the connection.
- In the “Local Resources” tab, uncheck as many resources as practical.
- If using a browser, disable hardware acceleration.
- Use an alternative to RDP, for example [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/).